# Adding MySql Workbench to favorites in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, mysql

I'm using Fedora 19 64 bit on my Samsung Series 9 Ultrabook and I have installed MySQL workbench 6 (mysql-workbench-community-6.0.7-1.fc18.x86_64) via the RPM downloaded from the MySQL website.

I'm unable to pin this application to favorites. I have tried creating the `mysql-workbench.desktop` at `/usr/share/applications/` and copied the `mysql-workbench.png` icon into `/usr/share/pixmaps/` file as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MySQL Workbench
Comment=MySQL Database Design, Administration and Development Tool
Exec=mysql-workbench
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=mysql-workbench
MimeType=application/vnd.mysql-workbench-model;
Categories=GTK;Database;Development;
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a desktop file created and in the right location, you're almost there. You can do one of two things:

1. Bring up the overview and search for the application; once you've found it, right click and *Add to Favorites* or simply drag to the launcher dashboard.
2. Set the dconf key `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`, either using the `dconf-editor` GUI or the `dconf` command-line tool.

Try

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

to see the current list, and `dconf write` to set it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that I did try to right click but I did not find any _Add to Favorites_ option. However I have not tried dragging or dconf. I'll give those a shot and let you know what transpires. Can you confirm if you had the option to _Add to Favorites_ upon right click?

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi Yes, I just confirmed. You need to find the icon in the Applications menu (panel? page? whatever it's called), or by searching in the Overview (mouse to the top left corner of the screen or hit the "windows" key). Finding it in a file manager won't do.

Comment: I tried dragging the icon over and I thought it worked. But when I clicked on it, I got 2 Workbench icons in the favorites bar. One with the white mysql icon (which is pinned and has the option to add to favorites) and another called the mysql-workbench-bin with a blue icon (with which I cannot do anything). At this point I have decided to stop worrying about this issue as it seems to be taking more time than it is worth to fix it. So thanks for your help.